# How to get current template name in a TWIG function

Tags: php, symfony, twig

let's say I have created a custom twig function: templateName.

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addFunction('templateName', new Twig_Function_Function('twig_template_name', array('needs_environment' => true)));
```

Is there a way to get the name of the current template(s) in php. I imagine something like this:

```
function twig_template_name(Twig_Environment $env, $values = null) {
  return $env->getCurrentTemplateName();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. This is not how you create twig functions (see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#id2). 2. What's the value of a function returning a template name, providing you're calling it in the template?

Comment: Hi. The code is just for illustration, but thanks for the input, I updated the question for better understanding. @2: I want to send an ajax request, that renders the exact same template.

Comment: You plan to send a template name from javascript. Since it's on a client side, it's not safe (client would be able to change the template name to render). I think you should rethink the way you designed your controllers/templates. Somehow you're able to decide which template to render when generating the page. Use the same logic when calling ajax.

Comment: I don't think it would be a security issue. If someone wants to change the way the browswer displays a page, there are easier ways. But you are right, it is not a clean. Maybe you can tell me a better way, when I am more precise. The function renders some content and an edit link. A user can edit the content inline, and it is stored in a database via ajax. Now I want this special content to be reloaded, without reloading the whole page. My initial idea was to render the same template again, cut out the modified content and send it back. Maybe you have a better idea to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For everyone who needs an answer to the initial question, I found a solution that twig itself is using in the Twig_Error class.

```
protected function guessTemplateInfo()
{
    $template = null;
    foreach (debug_backtrace() as $trace) {
        if (isset($trace['object']) && $trace['object'] instanceof Twig_Template && 'Twig_Template' !== get_class($trace['object'])) {
            $template = $trace['object'];
        }
    }

    // update template filename
    if (null !== $template && null === $this->filename) {
        $this->filename = $template->getTemplateName();
    }

    /* ... */
```

best regards!

Comment: Note that the format of the templatename will be different when called from the CLI (for example during cache-warmup) than from fpm/mod_php. CLI: `AppBundle:base.html.twig`, FPM: `@App/base.html.twig`.

Comment: $template->getSourceContext()->getPath() seems to contain the absolute path to the template file

Answer (score 4):

The solution proposed by Mario A did not work for me, but using debug_backtrace() is a great idea and a little modification made it work with a recent Twig version:

```
    private function getTwigTemplateName()
{
    foreach (debug_backtrace() as $trace) {
        if (isset($trace['object']) 
             && (strpos($trace['class'], 'TwigTemplate') !== false) 
             && 'Twig_Template' !== get_class($trace['object'])
        ) {
            return $trace['object']->getTemplateName() . "({$trace['line']})";
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addFunction(new Twig_SimpleFunction('twig_template_name', function() use ($twig) {

  $caller_template_name = $twig->getCompiler()->getFilename();

  echo "This function was called from {$caller_template_name}";

}));
```

**UPDATE:** as mentioned by [Leto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894097/leto), this method will NOT work from within cached (compiled) templates. If, however, you use shared memory caching (APC, Memcache) instead of Twig's caching or run this functionality in app that runs in an environment that doesn't have high traffic (think of back-end app for staff or branch of app that is only used to collect information about app's codebase) you can make it work by disabling Twig's caching (e.g. `$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('cache' => false));`). Make sure to carefully examine your use case though before disabling Twig's cache and using this method and see if you can solve that problem using different approach.

Comment: I think this only works at template compilation request.