# Getting template name in twig extension

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Is it possible to get the name of the template that is calling a method in a twig extension?

Example:

```
private $templateInUse;

public function __construct(){
    $templateInUse = $this->someMagicalFunction();
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getName() {
    return 'twig_extension';
}

public function getTokenParsers()
{
    return array(new TokenParser($this->templateInUse));
}
```

It would up eventually have an output of `some:file:path.html.twig`

Comment: In general, yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656835/how-to-get-current-template-name-in-a-twig-function

But it seems to be tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, you can get the template name from the stream itself.

```
class FooTokenParser extends Twig_TokenParser
{

    public function parse(Twig_Token $token)
    {

        $this->parser->getStream()->getFilename();
    }
}
```